# Can I use two ampersands in my logo?

Tags: grammaticality, orthography

I am  thinking of updating my logo.

Would it be wrong to write

> John Smith
>
> Advocate & Notary & Mediator

?

Comment: Wrong in that the grammar police will arrest you or wrong in that people will think 'He must be a lawyer: look at his logo'? Modern styles would almost certainly just use separators (eg flourishes) between the three terms.

Comment: You may want to use John Smith Advocate\Notary\Mediator. It depends on the presentation and design. This is the advertising prof in me speaking

Answer (score 1):

It reads poorly with two ampersands - by that I mean the reader will likely read it as *John Smith, Advocate and Notary and Mediator* which sounds awkward.

`John Smith: Advocate, Notary, & Mediator` - is worth a try.

However, if your logo is more **graphic design** and not plain text, take artistic license and go for it, people can understand it just fine. You can use ampersands or another separator if desired. In plain written text though, it is awkward and uncommon.

Comment: I'd drop the comma after Notary.

Comment: The classic oxford comma debate. I am a staunch believer in the oxford comma, but in a logo (s)he should style it in the way that presents the information as clearly as possible. I wouldn't use an ampersand at all and go for something more like gelolopez suggests in a comment on the OP, I just left it in there since it was so tied to the question.

Comment: I'm with Tim on this one, clarity is certainly an important element, but logos also involve aesthetic factors.